# Fast way to come up with solutions to $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I can solve this equation $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=1$ using the usual method but I am looking for a fast analytical method to solve this. Any hints ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this linear algebra as your dealing with an equation with exponents that are greater than 1

Comment: Quartic algebra?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HINT:

$x(x-3)=x^2-3x, (x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$

Write $x^2-3x=u$

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=x-{3 \over 2}$ to get $y^4-{ 5 \over 2} y^2 - {7 \over 16}$.

(A plot of the function shows a local maximum at ${3\over 2}$.)

Comment: I think reason of setting $y=\cdots$ is $$\frac{x+x-1+x-2+x-3}4=x-\dfrac32$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Nice.