# How to expand equations of bigger degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am 8th grade, and I have to solve this equation (I got it from a problem when I simplified):
$$ x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = 0 $$

I looked at some solutions in online solvers, but I don't understand how I should guess that $6x^3 = -x^3 + 7x^3$ or $11x^2 = -7x^2 + 18x^2$. I would be very grateful if you can explain to me how to expand it and solve it.

Comment: $x=1$ is obvious

Comment: The 0th coefficient of your polynomial is related to the product of the roots (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). So you can try all the factors of $24$ $(\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 6, \pm 12, \pm 24)$ to find a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can easily see that $x=1$ is a solution to the given equation. Thus, the given expression will be given as a product of $(x-1)$ with a polynomial of 3rd degree. More specifically :

$$x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = (x-1)(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)$$

Now, you can expand the right hand side and calculate $a,b,c$ and $ d$.

$$x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx - ax^3 - bx^2 - cx - d$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = ax^4+ (b-a)x^3 + (c-b)x^2 + (d-c)x-d$$

For the equation to hold, each polynomial term must be equal, thus the coefficient of each of the $x^4,x^3,x^2,x$ terms must be equal and of course the constants. Thus, $a,b,c$ and $d$ are given as :
$$\begin{cases} x^4 = ax^4 \\ 6x^3=(b-a)x^3 \\ 11x^2 = (c-b)x^2 \\ 6x = (d-c)x \\ -24=-d\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} a=1 \\ b=7 \\ c= 18\\ d = 24\end{cases}$$

Doind that, gives $a=1, b=7, c=18$ and $d=24$. Thus :

$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = x^3+7x^2+18x+24$$

You can apply any of the ways you've been taught to solve polynomials of 3rd degree and you shall get :

$$x^3+7x^2+18x+24 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (x+4)(x^2+3x+6) = 0$$

Thus the initial expression can be written as :

$$x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (x-1)(x+4)(x^2+3x+6) =0$$

This means that the solutions to the equation are $x=1$ and $x=-4$, since the quadratic involved has a negative discriminant, thus no real solutions. Of course, if you're interested to solve over complex numbers, then you'd consider the complex numbers that satisfy the quadratic as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately, I can't understand the algorithm. First, we are trying to see some obvious solutions? This is making me feel nervous because I think in Maths there isn't anything obvious. What happens then if we can't see a root at the beginning? I don't understand how do you get the second equation and the values of a, b, c and d. Also, I only know how to solve quadratic equations but I think I can solve this.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Hi dear Nikol. Okay, first of all, yes indeed we do try to find some obvious solutions. When the degree of a polynomial is getting high enough and you're asked to solve it by hand, then almost all of the times an obvious solution will be easy to be spoted. Moving on, since $x=1$ is a solution, you can factor our $(x-1)$. Since the polynomial you factored out is of 1st degree, the remaining should be of 3rd degree. You write that 3rd degree polynomial as $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Now, if you expand the right hand side you get what I mentioned (I am editing now to show you).

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Edited now. Let me know if there is something you want to be explained further.

Comment: Thank you! I got it! I really appreciate your help! And I will try to solve the polynomial of 3rd degree. Is Horner's method a good choice? And when I find one solution I will try the steps which you have described.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Always happy to help. Yes, Horner does the trick if the roots are simple numbers and you're familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$24=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$$

Set $x(x+3)=y$ to form a quadratic equation in $y$

Comment: I understood this after I had posted it. But I still want to understand what should I do in similar situations. Thank you!

Comment: @Nikol, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008509/fast-way-to-come-up-with-solutions-to-xx-1x-2x-3-1/1008510#1008510

Answer (score 0):

Tiny improvement to Rebellos' solution:

Once you see that $$x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24 = (x-1)(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)$$

it's more efficient to do polynomial division rather than multiplying the RHS and forming linear equations.

```
        x^3 + 7x^2 + 18x + 24
       -------------------
x - 1 | x^4 + 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x - 24
        x^4 - x^3
        ----------
              7x^3
              7x^3 - 7x^2
              -----------
                     18x^2
                     18x^2 - 18x
                     ------------
                            24x
                            24x - 24
                            --------
                                   0
```